# Integrating closed sourced mixed Swift and Objective-C framework in Swift application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

I created a mixed Objective-C and Swift framework which has a single API class written in Swift:

```
@import PrivateIncludes

@objc open class FrameworkApi : NSObject {
    @obj open static func setup(apiKey: String) {
    }
}
```

This class references multiple other class both: from Objective-C and Swift inside the framework.

My modulemap files imports multiple Objecive-C files:

```
module PrivateIncludes {
    header "./ObjcClassA.h"
    header "./ObjcClassB.h"
    ...
}
```

When integrating the framework in Objective-C application, everything is working as expected. I import the framework and use it without problems:

```
@import MyFramework;

[FrameworkApi setupWithApiKey:@""];
```

This works as expected.

On the other hand, when trying to import the framework from Swift code:

```
import MyFramework
```

the compiler complains:

```
ObjcClassA.h:10:9: 'ObjcClassB.h' file not found
```

Since `ObjcClassA` makes use of `ObjcClassB`. Even turning all the headers public (which I don't want to do) and copying then to *Headers* folder does not help.

It seems like I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add a bridging header to your project and import ObjcClassB.h to it.
Take a look a this document - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: These headers are not public (and should not be public). Even though, when exposing them to the outside world, they should be added to umbrella header of the framework, which, in turn should be added to bridging header of the application. Regretfully, this does not help, these headers cannot still be found.